# Uri.java line 475 android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init> com.google.android.gms.ads

Tags: android, admob

I'm getting an error from different device versions (Android 5 - Android 8) since I use ads:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0'
```

My error looks like this:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
   at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:475)
   at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java)
   at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:437)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.video.a.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14366046@14.3.66 (040306-213742215):13)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.video.gmsg.f.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14366046@14.3.66 (040306-213742215):148)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.j.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14366046@14.3.66 (040306-213742215):293)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.ac.run(Unknown Source:4)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.e.dispatchMessage(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14366046@14.3.66 (040306-213742215):5)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1518)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

any help is apreciated

Comment: I have the same problem, could you please share your solution when you find it?

Comment: Same here. With AdMob v12.0.1, started on October 26th. Multiple app versions started to report this issue at the same time.

Comment: The issue was solved on Nov 7th. I haven't seen any crashes since Nov 8th. You can also check the thread mentioned in @Aryan's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in version `17.0.0` either you're using

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'    //or
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.0.0'
```

You can check this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/JgVrHeRKcu4/XJAPHZ8RAQAJ) for more detail.

According to the [post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/JgVrHeRKcu4/IaIK0IjtAgAJ) from Mobile Ads SDK Team member, issue has been fixed but there is no ETA as of now.

---

**EDIT**

I found that above issue is not related to particular admob version. From last week most of the apps with AdMob start crashing, It doesn't matter what admob version you're using. I think there is issue with server side or how they delivered ads(may be getting null in response) and not handled in AdMob SDK level.

So Currently we've

- Issue with Server side
- May be some issue in version `17.0.0`

Issue already submitted to `Mobile Ads SDK` team so we've only option to wait for server side fixes or we may get another release after `17.0.0`.

Comment: yep, I downgraded to v15.0.0 and the same error persists, we're waiting AdMob solution as soon as possible

Comment: @Choletski Still no response from Mobile SDK Team regarding issue fixes but today version `17.1.0` has been deployed on Google's Maven repository, you can give a try :)

Comment: @Choletski Issue from server side has been resolved, response from most of developers that they are not getting above crash from last 24 hours and personally I've deployed some of apps with Admob version `17.0.0`

Comment: thx for your time. As you said, the problem seems to be gone, I'm still using v15.0.0 and crashes disappears

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this issue when I upgraded my ads dependency to the latest version, to find a proper solution keep checking this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/JgVrHeRKcu4/XJAPHZ8RAQAJ) as mentioned by @Aryan in other answer. As a workaround for now you can use the following dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
```

this will keep the crash from occurring.

Comment: nope, same error using `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0`

Comment: @Choletski What's your target SDK ??

Comment: I use SDK 19-28